# Regex MVC model Validation

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

This is a working regex script in JS:

```
var emailRegExp   = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;
```

How would I escape characters like \ and "

I would like to use it for my model validation like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/")]
```

But it fails when I escape with either two \ or using @ before the string.

**How would this script look like in a C# model validation?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the js delimiter that is the the forward slash present at the start and the end.

```
@"^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@""]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@""]+)*)|("".+""))@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$"
```

Comment: I would love to accept your answer but it fails with the " character.

@"^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"       <---- here

Comment: I had to escape the double quotes aswell like this: @"^(([^<>()[]\\.,;:\s@\""
Please edit your answer so I can accept it :)